# Classpath locations for jsp files in a Spring Boot Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, jar

I'm trying to write a Spring Boot Application that is capable of using ModelAndView to send out JSP files back to the caller.

Here is a Controller Method:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController
{
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView getAuthPage(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params)
    {
        System.out.println("In Login mapping!");

        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.setViewName("login");

        ModelMap models = view.getModelMap();
        models.addAttribute("message", "Log In");

        System.out.println("Returning View!");
        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm able to get that Method to Return.

Here are three of the fields in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
```

Here is a list of some of the places I've attempted to store the login.jsp file:

```
src/main/resources/templates (only place where I could see them in the jar file)
src/webapp
src/webapp/WEB-INF/views
```

Looking at some of the --debug output and this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround), the App seems to be looking in a folder called *META-INF/resources* . While there is a *META-INF* folder in the Jar, there is no *META-INF/resources* folder.

If the app is looking for *.jar/META-INF/resources.login.jsp* , is there a way, using Gradle, to ensure those jsp files are there. Otherwise, is there a way to have the app look for those JSP files in the *.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/templates/* which is where I currently am able to get those JSP files to in the JAR?

Right now, I just want the file to be detected (within the JAR) when the controller method returns so that my client doesn't get a **404 Not Found**

Note: I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811840/spring-boot-jsp-views-not-found) but the solution presented is to create a war instead of a jar and as of right now, I see that as a last resort type of solution.

Comment: JSP only work in a war (that is also mentioned in the Spring Boot guide related to drawbacks of using JSP with an embedded container).